# Монитор запросов

Tags: post, wireshark, kali-linux

Поднял сайт на своем пк, на пк установлен kali linux, на сайте форма и кнопка которая отправляет данные серверу через POST, какая утилита в терминале подойдет для мониторинга POST запосов с сайта, именно только с сайта не со всей локальной сети? Сайт будет работать пару дней, поэтому не охота писать специальный софт для принятия всего 20-50 запросов. Wireshark и brup suite не предлагать.

Comment: Ну, например, Apache имеет модуль mod_dumpio, который может логировать POST запросы. Другое дело, что в вашем вопросе есть «мониторинг»? Сбор, анализ значений, срабатывание триггеров, или обычная запись в файл?

Comment: Да. И зачем метка wireshark, если его не предлагать?